# Python injecting mock values for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a situation where I have in a Flask web app a function several layers down from the handler that I want to unit test. The function takes in a few parameters and changes them depending on reading different values from a database. Roughly like this:

```
  def func_to_test(a=1, b=10, c=100):
     # do some processing
     if (read_d_from_database() == 10):
        # override a to something else
        # do something
     if (read_X_from_database() == 45):
        # override b to 45
        # do something
     #etc..
```

How can I test this function from the outside in a standalone way so that I can simulate the read_d_from_database() etc returning different values each time?

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [`patch()` from `unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). It allows you to override how certain methods behave.

```
>>> @patch('__main__.SomeClass')
... def function(normal_argument, mock_class):
...     print(mock_class is SomeClass)
...
>>> function(None)
True
```